# Django multiple sites: Same code base, same database, but slightly different templates and static files

Tags: django

What method/framework should I use to run multiple websites that share 100% of the code base? The sites should all share a single database (but the sites do not share data. They only happen to use the same database to store data), but have slightly different templates, slightly different static files and completely different media files.

I am thinking of a method where I can have base templates and base static files that can be overridden with site specific templates/static files.

What method can I use to accomplish the task of running multiple sites in this way? Also important: What is a reasonable directory structure?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, if you had two different `settings` files you could re-use the same app server.  I typically recommend complete isolation with one site per app server, but it is up to you as to how you want to manage.  On one server, here is a layout you could use:

Put the common codebase at the bwlow, or something similar.

```
/home/gunicorn/app_name/common_code_base
```

But, you will need tow instances of gunicorn running on separate ports to serve the two different sites, so you will need two separate gunicorn configuration files (one for each DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE).  Then, you would use two separate nginx site configurations each of which fronted a separate gunicorn instance.  Something like:

```
                   / gunicorn (site1) \                            database(site1)
                  /                    \                         /
nginx (site1 & site2)                   ---- common code base ---
                  \                    /                         \
                   \ gunicorn (site2) /                           database (site2)
```

---

To have separate settings files, you put the common settings in a file called `common.py` and put site1 specific settings in `settings_site1.py` and site2 specific settings in `settings_site2.py`.  At the top of both of those files, put

```
from .common import *
```

To import all of the settings from `common.py`.  Now you can use the site1 settings by using:

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=path.to.settings_site1 python path/to/manage.py . . .
```

Comment: How is it possible to set up 2 settings files under the same project?

Comment: Have one called `settings_site1.py` and another called `settings_site2.py`.  Then you can use manage.py by setting the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE in the environment.

Comment: That's fine for development. But what about in production? How does the server know which settings file to read?

Comment: By setting DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE in the environment for gunicorn (http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html).